# Threads blocks each other

Tags: java, multithreading

I have incoming file download requests and each download is happening in different thread until pool size is exceeded.After a download completed, a processor processes the downloaded item. Download tasks does not run concurrently. What could cause this other than sync parts of task.getDownloadTask().download() or task.getProcessTask().process( eventhough there is not sync parts.

DownloadTaskProcessor

```
public class DownloadTaskEnqueuer {
    private static final BlockingQueue<Task> downloadQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private static final BlockingQueue<Task> processQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    private static final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

    public void offer(Task task) {
        return downloadQueue.offer(task);
    }

    public void createPool(int size) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            executor.execute(new DownloadTask(downloadQueue, processQueue);
            executor.execute(new ProcessTask(processQueue));
        }
    }
}
```

Download task

```
public class DownloadTask implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<Task> downloadQueue;
    private BlockingQueue<Task> processQueue;
    
    // constructor for initing two queue

    public void offer(Task task) {
        return processQueue.offer(task);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
           Task task = downloadQueue.poll();
           if (task != null) {
               task.getDownloadTask().download();
               offer(task);    
           } else {
               // sleep 250 ms 
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Process task

```
public class ProcessTask implements Runnable {
    private BlockingQueue<Task> processQueue;
    
    // constructor for initing queue
    
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
           Task task = processQueue.poll();
           if (task != null) {
                task.getProcessTask().process();
           } else {
               // sleep 250 ms 
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Use case (pseudo)

```
createPool(10);

listener.listen((task) -> {
    downloadTaskEnqueuer.offer(task);
}
```

Comment: Executors already create thread pools, and already know how to manage them and their task queues correctly without deadlocks. You should just be submitting tasks to the Executor as they arise. At present you're keeping a dog and barking yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are some design mistakes. Everyyime you write **Thread.sleep()** than you implementing the **busy waiting pattern**. This is not recommended.
Just try this:

```
public class DownloadTaskEnqueuer implements Runnable {
private final BlockingQueue<Task>           queue       = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
private final LinkedList<Future<Object>>    results     = new LinkedList<>();
private final Semaphore                     lock        = new Semaphore(0);
boolean                                     isRunning   = true;
private final ExecutorService               executor;

public DownloadTaskEnqueuer(int parallismCount) {
    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(parallismCount);
}

public void offer(Task task) {
    queue.offer(task);
    lock.release();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {
        lock.acquireUninterruptibly();
        Task task = queue.poll();
        Future<Object> futureResult = executor.submit(task);
        results.add(futureResult);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DownloadTaskEnqueuer dte = new DownloadTaskEnqueuer(10);
    Thread t = new Thread(dte);
    t.start();
}


public abstract class Task implements Callable<Object> {

abstract Object download();

abstract Object doProcess(Object downloadedObject);

@Override
public Object call() throws Exception {
    Object downloadedObject = download();
    Object processingResult = doProcess(downloadedObject);
    return processingResult;
}
```

}